# Supabase not storing session data in localstorage correctly

Tags: reactjs, vite, supabase

I have a vite + react + supabase application and I have a simple signup/login form. Signup and login seem to be working, except that session data is not being stored in localstorage (it's my understanding that it should).

So, refreshing the page does not keep user authenticated. I followed the tutorial to the T, so I'm not sure what would be keeping supabase from handling this correctly? Are there any gotchas I should be worried about?

Here's how supabaseClient.js file

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey)
```

And here's how I'm trying to reference the authenticated session

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { supabase } from "../supabaseClient"

export default function useAuth () {
    const [session, setSession] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
          setSession(session)
        })
    
        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
          setSession(session)
        })
      }, [])

    console.log('session ', session)

    return {
        session
    }
}
```

I then reference the hook in whatever component I want to use the user session in. It's just null every time. I verified in supabase client that the user gets created/logged in though. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. I think Supabase was not storing my session data because the user had not confirmed their email.

For anyone who runs into this issue, make sure the user you are trying to store session info for has their email confirmed. After I confirmed their email, it worked as expected.

I thought supabase turned this off by default, but it must be the opposite.